# Facebook app deactivated after detecting malware: `App Deactivated Due to Malicious Indicators Found in Your App`

Tags: android, facebook, malware-detection

I found the `AdFlex` (Ad-Malware) in my app and then I removed it and released the new Android app. Then Facebook checked and activated it again. But If someone with the old Android app which contains this malware logins in, then Facebook blocked my app again.

I tried to force all users to update the app to the new app but I think it's impossible.

How we can resolve this issue?

More information about AdFlex: https://pub.adflex.vn/documents/android-sdk-code.html

Comment: I tried to force all users to update the app to new one but I think it's impossible